# switch loops? while loops? currency converter program java

Tags: java

I am new to switch loops and am having multiple problems with this currency converter program I am trying to create.
First, I would like to loop the case 1 where the user keeps entering values until they type -1 so it stops and moves on. At the moment, it does not do this. Once I've entered the GPR values on switch 1 and then loop back to the menu keeping the original GPR stored values.

Code is here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Conversion {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double pound;
    double euro;
    double dollars;
    double yen;
    double rupees;
    double poundEuro;
    double poundDollars;
    double poundYen;
    double poundRupees;
    int Choice;


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner exchange = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please choose an option:");
    System.out.println("1.  Enter values and type -1 to stop");
    System.out.println("2.  Euros (1GBP = 1.28EUR)");
    System.out.println("3.  Dollars (1GBP = 1.51USD)");
    System.out.println("4.  Yen (1GBP = 179.80JPY)");
    System.out.println("5.  Rupees (1GBP = 95.60INR)");
    System.out.println("6.  Exit");

    Choice = input.nextInt();


    switch (Choice) {

    case 1:

        while (!exchange.equals("-1"));{
            pound = exchange.nextDouble();  
            System.out.print("Please enter your values you would like to exchange (Type '-1' to stop) ");
        }
    case 2:
        pound = exchange.nextDouble();
        dollars = 1.51;
        poundDollars = pound * dollars; 
        System.out.println("Your amounts in euros are" + poundDollars);

    case 3:
        pound = exchange.nextDouble();
        yen = 1.28;
        poundYen = pound * yen; 
        System.out.println("Your amounts in euros are" + poundYen);

    case 4:
        pound = exchange.nextDouble();
        rupees = 1.28;
        poundRupees = pound * rupees; 
        System.out.println("Your amounts in euros are" + poundRupees);

    case 5:
        pound = exchange.nextDouble();
        euro = 1.28;
        poundEuro = pound * euro; 
        System.out.println("Your amounts in euros are" + poundEuro);

    case 6:
        break;
    }

    input.close();
    exchange.close();


}
```

}

Comment: `switch` statements are not loops.

Comment: `"I am new to switch loops"` -- so am I. In fact, I've never heard of such a beast. I suggest that you use an actual loop structure, such as a while loop. The tutorials will help you with this.

Comment: No, no, `swich` loops, not `switch` loops.

Comment: Those `switch loops` will get you nine times out of ten

Comment: Dont use multiple scanners on one input. Use the same scanner. Your loop on exchange.equals("-1") does not make sense. You would need to compare pound (after readong it). Overall the menu does not make sense, why mix chosing the currency and entering values?

Comment: I think the `while` loop inside `case 1:` needs to be outside of the entire `switch`.  By itself, inside `case 1:`, it's not achieving very much.

Comment: `exchange.equals("-1")` will always be `false`, so I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish there (you read a double immediately afterward).

Answer (score 1):

`switch` is not a loop. It's a branching statement like `if`. It has `break`, but that is only present because you can "fall through" to the next `case` statements. Currently you are falling through on most of them, because you've forgot putting in the `break` statements between the cases.

Answer (score 0):

A switch statement isn't a loop.  Consider it a replacement for a series of else-if statements.  Your code actually reads more like this:

```
if(Choice == 1)
{

}
else if(Choice == 2)
{

}
else if(Choice == 3)
{

}
else if(Choice == 4)
{

}
else if(Choice == 5)
{

}
else if(Choice == 5)
{

}
```

However, your switch cases should be terminated with `break` statements.  If one is not, unlike the else-ifs above, execution will fall-through to the next case and execute the code in that one too, until it finally reaches a `break` statement or goes through all the cases.

What you want is for your while-loop to wrap AROUND your switch statement, but you should fix your while-loop first, since you terminated it with a semicolon, it is infinite.  While-loops don't need a semicolon at the end, unless you do not have a body for it but you do have some side-effect happening in the conditional check that will eventually cause it to end.

```
while( blah )
{
    switch( blah )
    {
        case 1:
            // Do stuff for this case
            break;
        case 2:
            // Do stuff for this case
            break;
        default:
            // Do stuff when no case is matched
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a bit confused. As noted by immibis in his comment, `switch` statements are not loops, so you need to enclose the `switch` statement *inside* a loop.

Then, you're missing the `break` statements at the end of each `case`. Quoting [the Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html):

> Each `break` statement terminates the enclosing `switch` statement. Control flow continues with the first statement following the `switch` block. **The `break` statements are necessary because without them, statements in `switch` blocks *fall through***: All statements after the matching `case` label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent `case` labels, until a `break` statement is encountered.

Your program should be something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Variable definitions
    while(true) {  // This is a little trick to force the application to repeat
                   // a task until you explicitly break the loop
        // Code to print your menu
        choice = input.nextInt();
        if(choice == -1 || choice == 6)
            break; // Break the while loop if choice is -1 or 6
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                // Your code for option 1
                break;
            case 2:
                // Your code for option 2
                break;
            // More cases
            default:
                System.out.println("You must enter an option between 1 and 6!");
                break; // Not strictly needed
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't put those `break` statements at the end of each `case` block, your program will fall through every option.

Please read:

- [The Java tutorials: The `switch` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)
- [The Java tutorials: The `while` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

---

Another option would be something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Variable definitions
    /*
       Now let's use a labeled loop
     */
    menu: while(true) { 
        // Code to print your menu
        choice = input.nextInt();
        switch(choice){
            case -1:  // Nothing goes here, so the execution will fall through
                      // to the next case
            case 6:
                break menu; // This will break the menu loop.
                            // Since the previous case simply falls through to 
                            // this one, this will happen if choice is 
                            // either -1 or 6
            case 1:
                // Your code for option 1
                break;
            case 2:
                // Your code for option 2
                break;
            // More cases
            default:
                System.out.println("You must enter an option between 1 and 6!");
                break; // Not strictly needed
        }
    }
}
```

More reading:

- [The Java tutorials: Branching statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)